# while loop script to retry and end if it meets condition

Tags: shell, while-loop

I'm trying to write a simple shell script to continuously call (curl) an API, retrieve the result, and just execute my response. The reason I'm using the whole loop condition is because I'm making an API call to a job thats running. The three responses I'm expecting are SUCCESS, FAILURE, or 'null' (job is still in progress). My script works when I execute it at the time the job either fails or succeeds.

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=`(curled API response - expecting "FAILURE", "SUCCESS", or null)`


while [ $RESULT ]
do
    if [ "$RESULT" == "FAILURE" ]
    then
        echo "FAILURE in Build"
        break
    elif [[ "$RESULT" == "SUCCESS" ]]
    then
        echo "SUCCESS in Build"
        break
    elif [[ "$RESULT" == *"null"* ]]
    then
        echo "Waiting for Test/Build to Complete:"
        sleep 10
        continue
    else
        echo "NO Response, please check API"
        break
    fi
done
```

While the API job is running, I do get the "waiting" condition when I execute my script, however, it just constantly executes the waiting condition even when the API job has completed. If I execute my script in a separate command line, I get the proper (success or failure) condition, but the existing execution of my script is still executing the waiting condition.

Essentially I'd like the script to retry from the beginning and check all conditions. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the RESULT writing into the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  RESULT=`(curled API response - expecting "FAILURE", "SUCCESS", or null)`
```